Gromov-Witten invariants for rational curves in $\mathbb{P}^n$
It is well known that the number or rational plane curves $C_d$ of degree $d$ passing through $3d-1$ general points of $\mathbb{P}^2$ can be computed (recursively) using the machinery of Gromov-Witten invariants.
Now I know that the result can be generalized to rational curves over $\mathbb{P}^n$ for $n>2$ but I was not able to find an explicit computation beside the classical case of $\mathbb{P}^2$. For instance, in the simplest case, is there a recursive formula for computing the number of rational curves of degree $d$ in $\mathbb{P}^n$ passing through $N$ codimension 2 linear subspaces, where $N$ is properly choosen such that the number is expected to be finite?
Thanks in advance
